# Akka Cluster application

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming

I'm trying to gather a bit of knowledge on using an Akka Cluster application for an ETL style application.
I've read through most of the documentation and I'm now looking on moving forward with writing the actual application so I'm here to see if anyone has worked on something before and has any recommendations.

The ETL will need to able to schedule and throttle HTTP requests to a variety of endpoints. I would like to find a way to publish the statistics of the application (response times from endpoints, overall time in the application, and collect errors).
The application should be autoscaled so that when the amount of scheduled requests is increasing over time the Akka Cluster will add nodes to respond to the influx of work.

I was thinking that each scheduled request would produce a UUID to track the work (identifying results and errors that happen). So after the external endpoints respond or don't the results could be placed on a Akka Stream that would post process the requests as part of the T and the L of the application.
If there are good patterns out there or anyone can make a recommendation I would greatly appreciate it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at kamon.io -- it's a library to provide metrics and tracing through a variety of technologies, and has an Akka tracing component. From the little I've worked with it, starting a trace requires just one method call.